# Can you grapple a swarm?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, grapple, swarm

While it doesn't make sense from a rules as intended perspective, I haven't seen anything in the Grapple section or your average swarm's stat-block that protect it from being grappled.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### No. But you've read the stat blocks correctly.

The [Monster Manual errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/MM_Errata.pdf) provide that "every swarm is immune to being grappled" as a condition immunity.